# Fatal error: Class __ not found

Tags: php

Last spring I was working on a project using PHP, and it was working well. I had no time to work on it later, but now after I changed hosting I want to work on it again. I send files in working directory, but the error appears. It says that can't find Class TemplateLogin in class Login

Login.php:

```
class Login extends TemplateLogin
```

TemplateLogin.php:

```
abstract class TemplateLogin extends Core
```

Login.php and TemplateLogin.php are in the same folder

Comment: Are you using an autoloader? Composer? Namespaces? or maybe just `require`s? There's many combinations of things that will work, but we'll need more context here to be of any help.

Comment: @HPierce maybe i can share my code here, because i don't think i'm using anything you noticed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file Login.php needs to require or include the file TemplateLogin.php:

```
require_once 'TemplateLogin.php';
```

Or php will not know how the class TemplateLogin is defined.

An alternative to manually including/requiring every file is to define an [autoloading function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Comment: where should i add this, because if i put it on the second line(before defining a class it doesn't work)

Comment: Think about it. Before you can refer to the class TemplateLogin, you have to include/require the file in which that class gets defined. It would therefore necessarily have to happen before you define Login.

Comment: oh, actually i just had to put require also in TemplateLogin

Comment: It can be a real pain in the ass to always include/require a file every time you want to use a class. The smart solution is to put all your classes in one folder (or some place that you can derive from just the class name) and then you define an autoloader. Read the link in the answer I provided. You should also ideally have one file that is included by every page -- ideally, all requests to your application should be routed through a single page. This gives you a chance to modify the behavior or your entire app in one single spot.